# Place button over Image View bottom Line

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using FrameLayout and want to place the button exactly like this:

[image: Sketch]

How can I do this in XML? The button needs to be over the bottom of the image view always.

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this could be easier done in RelativeLayout as such

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <ImageView (image) ...>
    <Button (button)
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding a small amount of padding to the image should also achieve the effect of it overlapping the bottom.
With this you should easily be able to put the button where you want.

Here's an example of the code being put into action and working on a test app I made up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/login_logo"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kej2l.png) an image displaying it in action, sorry for the less than ideal image I was using as an example.

Comment: But I need to center the button on the bottom line of ImageView, that's my problem

Comment: I'm getting
`Error:(176) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentCenter' in package 'android'`

Comment: Your relative layout cannot wrap content if this is the case. You need some sort of fixed height or relative height that you can set on your parent layout so it is big enough to hold the button staggered over the image. Essentially a relative layout will let you put the button wherever you want the tricky part is making it stagger the image within the relative layout instead of layering on top of it.

Comment: I added my xml, it's centering on the device screen, so when I rotate it, the button stays entirely over the ImageView

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, the button doesn't follow the image when the screen is rotated?

Comment: Possibly changing the button's layout width and height to a specified dp (as shown in the edited example) might help with what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Once again you need fixed heights to pull this off

Comment: Yes, as doubleA says you would need to set a fixed height (dp) in order to achieve what you are trying. My example shows the height and width with specific amounts, but just having the height, as shown in the image you made would be what you want. Adding padding to the bottom of the image will give you the effect of overlapping.

Comment: Sorry for all these comments, but I've updated the example code to show this, it should be as simple as replacing my image with yours and making the button functional.

Comment: I'd say thank you for all these comments! It's working!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this naturally in android (pre Lollipop). My suggestion is to trick you user into thinking you are staggering one view over the other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/full_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="148"
    android:clipChildren="false">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background_image_contentdescription"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in code when i am setting up this view.

```
//The large view is an Image with a fixed height of 120dp
int bgImageHeight = FSUtils.dpToPixels(120, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
//The small view is a Relative Layout with a fixed height of 56 dp.
int dataLeafHeight = FSUtils.dpToPixels(56, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
//The full header contains the two and its minimum height is set
// to the height of the large image + half the height of the small view
full_header.setMinimumHeight(bgImageHeight + dataLeafHeight/2);
```

Then you use align parent bottom and align parent top to pull the views to the top and bottom making the smaller view stagger the boundary of the big background view.

I believe there is a way to do this in the new OS LolliPop but i have not experimented with it yet. Maybe someone else can chime in on this.

Answer (score 0):

> You can achieve this by using a constriantLayout as your parent layout, it makes it easy that you can simply drag and drop items at any position in the parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Guideline` in `ConstraintLayout` its easy to achieve.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.37619698" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```